# Autenticação do Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk

Estou criando uma API e estou tentando implementar a autenticação com o Faceboook. Eis o cenário, existe 2 ambientes o *front-end* e o *back-end*, ambos estão em domínios diferentes. Ex:

**Front:**

```
http://meuappfront.com
```

**Back:**

```
http://minhaapiback.com
```

O *Front* vai autenticar com a SDK Javascript e enviar para o *Back* apenas o *Token* de acesso do Facebook, que por sua vez vai validar esse Token com o SDK PHP.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Preciso registrar uma APP no Facebook para cada dominio? E se vai funcionar autenticar o Token de acesso em APPs diferentes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar apenas um APP e nas configurações informar os domínios em que o seu APP vai executar.

E respondendo a segunda pergunta, O Token não autentica em APPs diferentes.

Comment: Olá Thiago, sua resposta está correta. Mas será que poderia adicionar mais alguns detalhes? Da forma que a resposta esta, pode causar dúvidas ao tentar fazer o que você diz.

Comment: Claro, one sec.

Comment: Já havia resolvido com apenas uma APP, mas obrigado por responder mesmo assim.